# Not sure how to set my variables correctly for existing code. Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

Im currently trying to run a function from a separate class within a viewcontrollers viewdidload(). A previous team of developers wrote the code and i am struggling to get it to work as im also very new to swift.

I havn't included all functions as it is very long but just wondering if i could get some advice, im getting the error "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" for the shapelayer values, i'm aware it is because they havn't been initialised but im struggling to figure out how to set the variables correctly without messing up the entire code, just hoping for a bit of guidance.

Im sure i probably need to explain more but theres a lot of code and iv been staring at it all day, let me know if i need to upload any more.

```
class TraceViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var canvasView: CanvasView!
  static var curLetter = "A"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    canvasView.letter = TraceViewController.curLetter
    canvasView.clearCanvas()
  }
}
```

Class:

```
class CanvasView:UIView { 
  var lineColour:UIColor!
  var lineWidth:CGFloat!
  var path:UIBezierPath!
  var touchPoint:CGPoint!
  var startingPoint:CGPoint!

  var initialPoint:CGPoint!

  var stroke1Done = false
  var stroke2Done = false
  var stroke3Done = false
  var stroke4Done = false
  var stroke5Done = false
  var stroke6Done = false
  var stroke7Done = false

 //Track current stroke and add all the shape layers into an array
  var currentStroke = 1
  var strokesArray = [CAShapeLayer]()

func drawShapeLayer() {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath //error here
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColour.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    //Add the shapes in array so that we can track it
    self.strokesArray.append(shapeLayer)

    self.setNeedsLayout()
}

func clearCanvas() {
    guard path != nil else {return}
    path.removeAllPoints()
    self.layer.sublayers = nil
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    print("Hello")
    stroke1Done = false
    stroke2Done = false
    stroke3Done = false
    stroke4Done = false
    stroke5Done = false
    stroke6Done = false
    stroke7Done = false

    goNext = false

    updateStrokePoints()

    updateStrokeDifference()

    currentStroke = 1
 }
}
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the fatal error?

Comment: Hi i just commented in where the error occurs. It happens at shapeLayer.path, and if comment that variable out it happens to each of the shapeLayer properties.

Comment: You declared `var path:UIBezierPath!` but you have not yet created it.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to occur because you have not set the path before using it. You need to set the `path` before actually calling it.

first:

```
var path: UIBezierPath?
```

then:

```
path = UIBezierPath()
```

and finally, use it:

```
shapeLayer.path = path?.cgPath
```

Also, remember to use `?` instead of `!` it always bad practice to force unwrap.

Comment: Hey mate, i have tried this and added optionals to the end of each variable where an error comes up for them but i'm also now getting riddled with new errors throughout my code. Would i be able to get in touch with you to take glance at my code, the class is quite long. Iv been struggling to get this running all day :(

Comment: It is not *always* bad practice to declare variables as required (note that IBOutlets are done so). @Slacky88, what you need to do is trace the call to `drawShapeLayer()` and look for somewhere in the code that *is* creating the path, and find out why `drawShapeLayer()` is being called before that point.